# InfixToPostfix convert char to string

Tags: shunting-yard

How would I convert the chars in this code to Strings? The InfixToPostfix has to be able to take in Strings rather than chars so it can accept double digit numbers and spaces. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class InfixToPostfix
{
private Stack operators = new Stack();

public InfixToPostfix()
{

}

public String toPostfix(String infix)
{
    char[] characters = new char[100];
    int i;
    int length = infix.length();
    infix.getChars(0, length, characters, 0);
    char operator;
    String output = "";

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (isOperator(characters[i]))
            if (operators.empty())

                operators.push(characters[i]);
            else
            {
                if (operatorLessPrecedence(characters[i]))

                {
                    do
                    {
                        output = output + operators.pop();
                    }
                    while (!operators.empty() && operatorLessPrecedence(characters[i]));
                    operators.push(characters[i]);
                }
                else

                    operators.push(characters[i]);
            }
        else

            output = output + characters[i];
    }
    while (!operators.empty())
    {

        operator = (char)operators.pop();
        output = output + operator;
    }
    return output;
}

/**
 * operator
 */

public boolean isOperator(char c)
{
    if ( c == '*' ||
         c == '/' ||
         c == '+' ||
         c == '^' ||
         c == '-')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public boolean operatorLessPrecedence(char o)
{
    int operatorPrecedence = precedence(o);
    int tosPrecedence = precedence((char)operators.peek());
    return (operatorPrecedence <= tosPrecedence);
}

/**
 * precedence
 */
public int precedence(char o)
{
    switch (o)
    {
        case '+': return 1;
        case '-': return 1;
        case '*': return 2;
        case '/': return 2;
        case '^': return 3;
    }
    return 5;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would split the code into two with a lexical analysis phase which splits the input into set of tokens. These are then passed to the shunting yard algorithm, which uses an array of tokens. In the lexing phase you can use regular expressions to detect the different type of input. Say /\d+/ detects sequence of one or more digits.